# VBA Macro Integration with Micros Simphony iQuery: Connecting and Interacting

Tags: vba, database, automation, integration

I am trying to establish a connection and interact with Micros Simphony iQuery using a VBA macro. Specifically, I need to perform certain operations or retrieve data using VBA. I'm encountering challenges in figuring out the necessary steps or code snippets to achieve this integration.

I have explored the Micros Simphony iQuery documentation and tried to find relevant resources online, but the information is scarce or not specific to VBA integration. I expected to find clear examples or documentation explaining how to use VBA to connect to Micros Simphony iQuery and perform basic queries or actions.